# How to make mysql data array clickable

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database, mysqli

I have to extract data from my MySQL database, everything goes well the data is displayed in the form of a table which here is the code:

```
<?php
    $no     = 1;
    $total     = 0;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {
        $category  = $row['category'] == 0 ? '' : number_format($row['category']);
        echo '<tr>
                <td>'.$no.'</td>
                <td>'.$row['id'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['url'].'</td>
                <td>'. $row['code'] . '</td>
                <td>'.$category.'</td>
            </tr>';
        $total += $row['category'];
        $no++;
    }?>
```

Except that I wish the data ". $row['url']." be **clickable** because it's an url. I tried this without result. This show nothing :

```
echo '<a href="'.$row['url'].'">'.$row['url'].'</a>';
```

and this too:

```
'<td><a href="'.$row['url'].'">'.$row['url'].'</a></td>'
```

Here is the link: [data table](http://softsys.tk/displaying_data1.php)

Comment: The first one should work

Comment: What you posted should work, being the `echo '<a href="'.$row['url'].'">'.$row['url'].'</a>';` one.

Comment: You have some other error as your code is fine

Comment: "<td><a href='{$row['url']}'>{$row['url']}</a></td>". You can try this, but your code is fine. Make sure you have actual data in the $row variable

Comment: Also be sure to inspect your output HTML to make sure it is not malformed.

Comment: I finally replaced : <td>'.$row['url'].'</td> by <td><a href="'.$row['url'].'">'.$row['url'].'</a></td> and it works. Thanks.